# How to know if a particular part of Header in CollectionView is scrolled out of Screen bounds?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uicollectionview

I want to get a callback or notification as soon as my segment control is out of the screen bounds. My collection view has a Custom header view at top.

In the past when I had only 1 UIElement in my Header view I used the methods

`func collectionView(UICollectionView, willDisplaySupplementaryView: UICollectionReusableView, forElementKind: String, at: IndexPath)`

and

`func collectionView(UICollectionView, didEndDisplayingSupplementaryView: UICollectionReusableView, forElementOfKind: String, at: IndexPath)`

to achieve this callback so that I can call my particular function when this happens.

But I have a bit more complex header now with few more UIElements. Is there a way I can get a notification or callback as soon as the Segment control is out of screen bounds from the screenshot ?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried by implementing `scrollViewDidScroll` method as like below?

```
var isSegmentedHidden = false
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 50.0 && isSegmentedHidden{ //Here 50.0 is the height of your segmented control plus vertical padding if any.

        isSegmentedHidden = false

        //Call your function here, once segmented control is visible
    }

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 50.0 && isSegmentedHidden == false{ //Here 50.0 is the height of your segmented control plus vertical padding if any.

        isSegmentedHidden = true

        //Call your function here, once segmented control is invisible
    }

}
```

Comment: Haven't tried looking at ScrollView methods. Will give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Please don't forgot to accept the answer, if it works in your case. Otherwise let me know, if you need further help.

Comment: Sure, working on it now. Will revert back. Thanks a lot.